# htaccess rewriteengine better looking get requests

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im trying to redirect to different pages. But it isn't working does anyone know how to fix it?

```
RewriteRule ^test assets/php/test/home.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^test/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) assets/php/test/menu.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^test/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) assets/php/test/player.php?id=$1&sec=$2 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)/(.*)$ assets/php/test/player.php?id=$1&sec=$2&type=dir [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ assets/php/test/testmenu.php?id=$1&type=dir [NC,L]
```